# How to create a new user using API in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, api

I am very new to JAVA and I need to create a HTTP-based RESTful API SMP and I am working on the first API, which needs to create a user and insert it into database. I have already created the database and tables in MYSQL. I found some sample code online and I am trying to alter it to work for what I need but it is not working, no errors just not putting anything in database. The description of the API with expected output plus the code I have so far is below. Not entire code just the code for this API. So any help on what I am doing wrong and need to do to get his working would be great. Also in the API.java is where I need to put each endpoint and I add the helper functions that do the SQL functions in DBEngine.java.

```
/api/createuser     // create a new Instatwitsnapbook user
// Input: curl -d '{"handle":"@cooldude42", "password":"mysecret!", "fullname":"Angus Mize", "location":"Kentucky", "xmail":"none@nowhere.com", "bdate":"1970-07-01"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:9990/api/createuser (Links to an external site.)
// Output: {"status":"4"} // positive number is the Identity.idnum created.
// Output: {"status":"-2", "error":"SQL Constraint Exception"}. [EDIT 04/14]
// etc.
```

API.java

```
@GET
    @Path("/createuser")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createuser() {
        String responseString = "{}";

        try {
            Map<String, String> teamMap = Launcher.dbEngine.getUsers();
            responseString = Launcher.gson.toJson(teamMap);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(500).entity(exceptionAsString).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(responseString)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    } // createuser
```

DBEngine.java

```
public Map<String,String> createuser() {
        Map<String,String> userIdMap = new HashMap<>();

        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try
        {
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            String queryString = null;
            queryString = "INSERT INTO Identity (handle, password, fullname, location, xmail, bdate)";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
            // No parameters, so no binding needed.
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                //String userId = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("idnum"));
                String handle = rs.getString("handle");
                String password = rs.getString("pass");
                String fullname = rs.getString("fullname");
                String location = rs.getString("location");
                String xmail = rs.getString("email");
                String bdate = rs.getString("bdate");


                userIdMap.put(handle, password, fullname, location, xmail, bdate);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userIdMap;
    } // createuser()
```

Comment: You are trying to put in this map:  

    Map<String,String> userIdMap = new HashMap<>();

A sequence of 6 strings, that cannot work.

Comment: Maybe you need to learn JDBC first. there are lots of tutorials out there. here's one
[JDBC](https://www.javaguides.net/p/jdbc-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve this:

```
/api/createuser     // create a new Instatwitsnapbook user
// Input: curl -d '{"handle":"@cooldude42", "password":"mysecret!", "fullname":"Angus Mize", "location":"Kentucky", "xmail":"none@nowhere.com", "bdate":"1970-07-01"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:9990/api/createuser (Links to an external site.)
// Output: {"status":"4"} // positive number is the Identity.idnum created.
// Output: {"status":"-2", "error":"SQL Constraint Exception"}. [EDIT 04/14]
// etc.
```

Then you need POST method in your API not GET.
One tutorial on APIs [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)